Projective Geometry Question on Proving Equality of Two Angles
I have been trying to solve question 3 from this handout but have not been able to make much progress. The question is:

$AD$ is the altitude of an acute triangle $ABC$. Let $P$ be an arbitrary point on $AD$. $BP$, $CP$ meet
$AC$, $AB$ at $M$, $N$, respectively. $MN$ intersects $AD$ at $Q$. $F$ is an arbitrary point on side $AC$. $FQ$ intersects line $CN$ at $E$. Prove that $∠FDA = ∠EDA$.

My attempt:
I first extended $MN$ to meet $BC$ at $R$. Then Lemma 2 in the handout applied here gives that $(C,B;D,R)$ and $(M,N;Q,R)$ are harmonic. $(A,P;Q,D)$ is the intersection of the pencil $C(M,N;Q,R)$ with the line $AD$ so $(A,P;Q,D)$ is also harmonic. Call the point where $FE$ and $AB$ intersect $F'$. The pencil $E(A,P;Q,D)$ intersects with $AB$ to give that $(A,N;F',B)$ is harmonic.
From this point I have been unable to make any further progress. How would one solve this using projective geometry techniques?

Denote $ED \cap AC = \{K\}$, and $DF \cap CE = \{X\}$.
Claim: Lines $AX, KP, DC$ are concurrent.
Proof: (There might be a simpler proof, but...) by Desargues' Theorem, it is equivalent to prove that the following three points are collinear:

$AK \cap XP = \{ C \}$,
$AD \cap XC = \{ P \}$,
$KD \cap PC = \{ E \}$.

As we know that the points $C,P,E$ are collinear, Desargues' Theorem implies that the lines $AX, KP, DC$ are concurrent. $\blacksquare$
Denote the common point of the lines $AX, KP, DC$ by $Z$. Now, we look at triangle $\Delta DAC$, and apply Lemma 2 and Lemma 5 from the handout you provided to make a conclusion regarding the desired two angles.

The lines $DF, CP, AZ$ are concurrent; therefore, by Lemma 2, $(K,F ; C,A)$ is harmonic.
$AD \perp DC$, and $(K,F ; C,A)$ is harmonic; therefore, by Lemma 5, $DC$ is the angle bisector of $FDK$, i.e., $\angle FDC = \angle CDK = \angle EDB$ (opposite angles).
As $AD \perp BC$, We have $\angle FDA = 90^\circ - \angle FDC$ and $\angle EDA = 90^\circ - \angle EDB$, which together with the previous bullet point imply that $ \boxed{ \angle FDA = \angle EDA } $, as desired.


If $AD \perp DC$ and $(K,F ; C,A)$ harmonic can we just use lemma 5 to go straight to $AD$ bisects $\angle FDK$, so, $\angle FDA = \angle EDA$? ALso, what was the motivation behind extending those specific lines to get $K$, how were you able to see that showing $AX, KP, DC$ were concurrent would help?

We are being asked angle equality at a right angle, so it immediately resembles Lemma 5. As the top vertex has to be $D$ (because that's where the right angle is), there are only a few choices for the line on which we will seek the 4 harmonic points. $AC$ was likely to work well, and point $K$ arised when considering line $AC$.

After establishing the goal to be proving that $(K,F;C,A)$ is harmonic, one thinks about how that can be done. Lemma 2 is a natural way, as the four points resemble the configuration there. But for Lemma 2 to be applied successfully, we need the collinearity of $K$, $P$ and the intersection of lines $AX$ and $DC$. The four points are harmonic if and only if this is true. And that is how the attempt to prove the concurrency of $AX,KP,DC$ arised.

Oh, and for your first question, yes, seeing $AD$ as the angle bisector to conclude the angle equality works too. In fact, when there are two perpendicular lines in such configuration, one line is angle bisector (of the inner angle, or acute angle) if and only if the other is angle bisector too (of the outer angle, or obtuse angle).
